# Heroku CI test app deletes /spec directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ruby-on-rails-5.1, heroku-ci

For some unexplainable reason it appears as though when Heroku CI is building the app in the test environment it deletes my /spec directory.

The error below says, `require': cannot load such file -- spec_helper (LoadError)`

When I use the Heroku debugger `heroku ci:debug --pipeline myapp` I see that there is no spec directory. If I run `rake` or `bundle exec rake` it gives me the same error that I see in the build UI.

Why could possibly be deleting this directory?

```
-----> Running test command `rake`...
/app/vendor/ruby-2.3.7/bin/ruby -I/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.7.1/lib:/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rspec-support-3.7.1/lib /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.7.1/exe/rspec --pattern spec/\*\*\{,/\*/\*\*\}/\*_spec.rb
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.7.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1455:in `require': cannot load such file -- spec_helper (LoadError)
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.7.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1455:in `block in requires='
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.7.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1455:in `each'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.7.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1455:in `requires='
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.7.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration_options.rb:112:in `block in process_options_into'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.7.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration_options.rb:111:in `each'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.7.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration_options.rb:111:in `process_options_into'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.7.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration_options.rb:21:in `configure'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.7.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:99:in `setup'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.7.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:86:in `run'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.7.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:71:in `run'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.7.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:45:in `invoke'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.7.1/exe/rspec:4:in `<main>'
/app/vendor/ruby-2.3.7/bin/ruby -I/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.7.1/lib:/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rspec-support-3.7.1/lib /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rspec-core-3.7.1/exe/rspec --pattern spec/\*\*\{,/\*/\*\*\}/\*_spec.rb failed
-----> test command `rake` failed with exit status 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In heroku, there's something called a .slugignore file. Someone added the /spec directory to that file, so my CI builds couldn't run.

Don't add your spec directory to .slugignore!